# 500 internal Server Error while setting up django in apache

Tags: python, django, apache, web, apache2

I was working to setup apache2 for my django and while i started my apache server it shows 500 error
`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match t`your text`his virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    Alias /static /var/www/isvr/static
    <Directory /var/www/isvr/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/isvr/isvr_certs>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-path=/var/www/isvr python-home=/var/www/isvr/myprojectenv
    WSGIProcessGroup myproject
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/isvr/isvr_certs/wsgi.py

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

`

this is my conf file can someone please help me with that.

I was about to setup my django project and followed the digitalocean guide to do so but after I restarted the server it shows 500 internal server error.

Comment: Can you set DEBUG=True temporarily for a more detailed 500 error page?